# What would be the appropriate way to depict an occupation of an employee within the class diagram in relationship to the c++ implementation?

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram

Let's say I have a base class `User` that holds all the necessary info (login, name, mail ...). There's `Administrator` class deriving from `User` that can create new and delete existing `User`s.

I need 3 more classes: `Manager`, `Worker` and `Project`. Both `Manager` and `Worker` derive from `User` but there's no need for additional members or methods within these which makes them empty classes.

In terms of visual representation I find this clear to understand if I aggregate `Manager` and `Worker` to the `Project` like this:

[image: class diagram bit - aggregation]

The thing is that I'd also like `Administrator` to have access to the list of all the `Managers` and the list of `Workers`. Also `Project` should be able to return its `Manager` and `Worker`s. In C++ to get such list I'm afraid I would have check the class type of each `User` to filter it out. I feel this is not the right way or is it?

A solution to this could be not creating `Manager`, neither `Worker` classes at all but rather adding a `User` attribute called occupation/designation that would be a string. Then the filtering process would get more straightforward and probably less costly.

If I took this route I'd end up with inaccurate diagram in which multiple `User`s are aggregated to the `Project` (or multiple projects) and no way to distinguish between the manager and the workers.

Could somebody please shed some light on this topic and maybe provide some graphical example?

Comment: I suggest you need to consider the roles a bit more carefully. For example, consider if it makes sense to view Manager, Worker, and even Administrator as roles that are associated with some functions or capabilities (e.g. administration rights) rather than separate type of user.  Also, consider the fact that some users may have multiple roles (e.g.  a worker on project A may manage project B and administer project C, etc).   So, when building a list of managers of a project, it may may sense extract a list of all users with a role managing that project.

Comment: I would agree with Peter. Without any more information about your problem domain, I would see Manager, Admin and Worker as "Roles" rather than types of User.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Peter. Without any more information about your problem domain, I would see Manager, Admin and Worker as "Roles" rather than types of User. Something like this:

[image: Users and Roles]